# Wordpress permissions issue

Tags: wordpress

I'm having some issues trying to make my Wordpress installation "bullet proof".  I was installing Wordpress on my testing server, when I noticed that I had a permission problem with folders and themes installation. I tried to fix it using the following commands, located in [this SF answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/43188/securing-wordpress-blog-installation/43788#43788):

For Directories:

```
find [your path here] -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

For Files:

```
find [your path here] -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

You have to omit to use this command for /wp-includes/.

Now I just see a blank screen in my Wordpress directory.  I don't want to `chmod 777` the Wordpress directory.  That would fix the problem, but would create a security issue.

Comment: check your error log why you are white screening

Comment: well I just change the permissions to 777 again hahaha and now I'm able to see my regular wordpress, now I'm wondering why in my Mac OSX I did not have problems like this one, I just intalled MAMP, downloaded the last wordpress package and that's it!  is it any other setting in Apache or something that I have to check?

Comment: I got it! 

Finally It's working!  

I just switch my user for root and then reInstalled wordpress, and that's it! I didn't have to chmod any file! pffff! I'm tired! need a beer! hahahaha

Answer (score 1):

Apache doesn't need to write to any of the web root in order to make wordpess function properly, all it needs to do is *read*

So, given that..the last octal in your UNIX permissions can be set to 0 always (so in reality, this would be 750/640)

Depending on ownership, you may need to run 770/660 inside of wp-content in order to allow the apache UID to write/move into that directory. This is an uncool solution, as it means apache gets pretty much full access on wp-content and below..so ideally you want the files to be owner by someone other than apache...preferably a human being.

I've written up a blog post on [wordpress file permissions](https://www.xreflow.co.uk/wordpress-file-permissions/) which you might want to take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup it can happen that those settings are not permissive enough. You may need to grant write access (77*) to the group (*HTTP* server process) too, at least to selected files/directories.

See [**Changing File Permissions**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) on ***WordPress.org*** for more information.